# Auto layout cell based on subview or custom cell height

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, subview, uitableview

[image: Text overflow out of cell]

In the image. Comments has a textview that has text overflown to below 3 cells . Ideally that should not happen.

I have a tableview with custom cells as xib files and some custom cells are subviews. Please let me know how to add auto layout for this subviews or xib's.

I read many posts they suggested.below code. But it doesn't work.

1. In ViewDidLoad. 
   self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50;

Please suggest a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Please explain your question more.

Comment: In heightForRowAtIndexPath you should return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Answer (score 0):

It will works, but you need to update the height everytime a new character is input, so in your `cellForRow`, add `textview.delegate = self`, and in the `textViewDidChange`, do `tableView.beginUpdate()` and `tableView.endUpdate()`, the cell height will update correctly